# High performance impression tracking

Tags: php, solr, redis, gearman

Basically, one part of some metrics that I would like to track is the amount of impressions that certain objects receive on our marketing platform.
If you imagine that we display lots of objects, we would like to track each time an object is served up.

Every object is returned to the client through a single gateway/interface. So if you imagine that a request comes in for a page with some search criteria, and then the search request is proxied to our Solr index.

We then get 10 results back.

Each of these 10 results should be regarded as an impression.

I'm struggling to find an incredibly fast and accurate implementation.

Any suggestions on how you might do this? You can throw in any number of technologies. We currently use, Gearman, PHP, Ruby, Solr, Redis, Mysql, APC and Memcache.

Ultimately all impressions should eventually be persisted to mysql, which I could do every hour. But I'm not sure how to store the impressions in memory fast without effecting the load time of the actual search request.

## Ideas  (I just added option 4 and 5)

1. Once the results are returned to the client, the client then requests a base64 encoded URI on our platform which contains the ID's of all of the objects that they have been served. This object is then passed to gearman, which then saves the count to redis. Once an hour, redis is flushed and the count is increments for each object in mysql.
2. After the results have been returned from Solr, loop over, and save directly to Redis. (Haven't benchmarked this for speed). Repeat the flushing to mysql every hour.
3. Once the items are returned from Solr, send all the ID's in a single job to gearman, which will then submit to Redis..
4. **new idea** Since the most number of items returned  will be around 20, I could set a X-Application-Objects header with a base64 header of the ID's returned. These ID's (in the header) could then be stripped out by nginx, and using a custom LUA nginx module, I could write the ID's directly to Redis from nginx. This might be overkill though. The benefit of this though is that I can tell nginx to return the response object immediately while it's writing to redis.
5. **new idea** Use `fastcgi_finish_request()` in order to flush the request back to nginx, but then insert the results into Redis.
6. Any other suggestions?

### Edit to Answer question:

The reliability of this data is not essential. So long as it is a best guess. I wouldn't want to see a swing of say 30% dropped impressions. But I would allow a tolerance of 10% -/+ acurracy.

Comment: How critical is the data?  If you lose, say, 100 impressions, is that bad?  If you lose 1 is that bad?  If there's some flexibility in this, then perhaps there's some sort of cached map with a thread that comes alive to persist it.

Comment: Also, what's the retrieval need of this data?  Do you need to be able to query it immediately and get timely results?  Or could you dump the impressions to a log of some sort and process that nightly in a batch job?

Comment: Marvo, the data is not critical. It's used in order to provide statistics to the owners of the objects. Providing them details such as click throguh rating etc. Losing some of the data is okay. I would expect to lose some regularly, (such as when I restart a server and the past hours results haven't been flushed back to mysql). I was going to take the results from Redis and push to mysql.

Comment: About what kind of numbers are we talking? How many objects and impressions and if you have any growth estimation.

Comment: Hi, I'm also attempting to track impressions. Are you concerned about also including bot traffic in your results? This could move your accuracy needle more than your allowable threshold. If so, what method have you come up with to filter this traffic? I'm curious to know :)

Comment: No, I didn't consider bottraffic. The way our archiectecture works is that we don't know at the time of a request where the request has come from, or even where it's intended to be displayed. If we needed to factor in bot traffic to adjust... we would have to do it after the fact. Check for bot requests, then manually adjust..

Answer (score 2):

I see your two best options as:

1. Using the increment command I redis to incremenent counters as you pull the dis. Use the Id as a key and increment it in Redis. Redis can easily handle hundreds of thousands of increments per second, so that should be fast enough to do without any noticeable client impact. You could even pipeline each request if the PHP language binding supports it. I think it does.
2. Use redis as a plain cache. In this option you would simply use a Redis list and do an rpush of a string containing the IDs separated by eg. a comma. You might use the hour of the day as the key. Then you can have a separate process pull it out by grabbing the previous hour and massaging it however you want to into MySQL. I'd you put an expires on keys you can have them cleaned out after a period of time, or just delete the keys with the post-processing process.

You can also use a read slave to do the exporting to MySQL from if you have very high redis traffic or just want to offload it and get as a bonus a backup of it. If you do that you can set the master redis instance to not flush to disk, increasing write performance.

For some additional options regarding a more extended use of redis' features for this sort of tracking see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11441293/incrementing-hundreds-of-counters-at-once-redis-or-mongodb/11456332#11456332) You could also avoid the MySQL portion and pull the data from redis, keeping the overall system simpler.

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like #2, and hand the data off to the fastest queue you can to update Redis counters.  I'm not that familiar with Gearman, but I bet it's slow for this.  If your Redis client supports asynchronous writes, I'd use that, or put this in a queue on a separate thread.  You don't want to slow down your response waiting to update the counters.

Comment: You might also asynchronously log to a file in a form suitable to load into MySQL as that's your eventual target.  Say, write to a tab file and when the logfile rotates, run a `LOAD DATA INFILE` to push into the database.